# Simultaneous equation with curve and a line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$2x+5y=1;$$
$$x^2+2xy=2y^2+1.$$
The answer is $(3,-1)$, but I keep overcomplicating the solution with fractions and I just want the easiest solution possible.

Comment: But what did you try? (Don't be afraid of fractions either, they're just divisions!)

Comment: Not afraid, just that im pretty sure there is an easier way and since I won't have much time during a test it would be nice to have a general solution to all of these kind of questions.

Comment: I mean I figured it out(although long) thats its (3,-1). Just want an easier way if possible

Answer (score 2):

Lets try like this
$$2x+5y=1\\x^2+2xy-2y^2=1$$Now square the first equation $$(2x+5y)^2=1\\x^2+2xy-2y^2=1$$Multiply the second by $4$ $$4x^2+20xy+25y^2=1\\4x^2+8xy-8y^2=4$$
Then first minus the second
$$12xy+33y^2=-3\\4xy+11y^2=-1\\y(4x+11y)=-1\\y(2(2x+5y)+y)=-1\\y(2+y)=-1\\y^2+2y+1=0$$
From there $y=-1$ then easily $2x-5=1$ implies $x=3$

Answer (score 2):

$2x+5y>0$.

We have, $$x^2+2xy-2y^2=(2x+5y)^2$$ or
$$(x+3y)^2=0.$$

Thus, $y=-1$ and $x=3$. The answer is $\{(3,-1)\}$.

Done!